# dcast() gives me an error message

Tags: r

I am trying to use `dcast()` to change a long format data into a wide format data. I am using the data frame "airquality" that is built into `R`.

When I run the code below, I get this error message:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'variable' not found.

I have tried to search for an answer here but I have not seen one that is specific to the function `dcast()`.

```
airquality_cast1 <- dcast(airquality, month + day ~ variable)
```

I see that the problem is with the last bit of the code, but I can't seem to figure out what it is. Was I supposed to assign variable to some object before running this code? Or is there some package I need to install for this to work?

Thank you!

Comment: The dataset `airquality` doesn't have a `variable` column `names(airquality)#
[1] "Ozone"   "Solar.R" "Wind"    "Temp"    "Month"   "Day"`  DId you meant to `melt` it to `long` format and then `dcast`?

Comment: Thank you! Yes,  I actually needed to `dcast()` the data frame in `long format` that I created. I was using the original data in the code above, which is already in `wide format`. Makes sense now.